# How to get a minimum value and the year it represents

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a list of orders in a table. these all have a date against them. How do I write a query to return the minimum orders in a year and the associated year.

```
SELECT Max(YearCounts.[CountForYear]) AS [MinForYear] 
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(PK) AS [CountForYear]   FROM Orders
WHERE DATEPART( year , TransactionDate) > '2002'
GROUP BY DATEPART( Year, TransactionDate ) ) YearCounts
```

So I am looking for 98008 orders in 2003 as an example

Thanks for the answers, I checked them out, the sub query option executed fastest. I take on board the single quotes comments, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `TOP 1`

```
SELECT TOP 1 YearCounts.[CountForYear] AS [MinForYear], 
       YearCounts.[YEAR] 
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(PK) AS [CountForYear],
               DATEPART( year , TransactionDate)  as [YEAR]  FROM Orders
               WHERE DATEPART( year , TransactionDate) > '2002'
               GROUP BY DATEPART( Year, TransactionDate ) ) YearCounts 
ORDER BY YearCounts.[CountForYear]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a subquery, just by using `top` and `order by`:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(year, TransactionDate), COUNT(PK) AS CountForYear
  FROM Orders o
  WHERE DATEPART(year , TransactionDate) > 2002
  GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, TransactionDate ) 
  ORDER BY COUNT(PK) DESC ;
```

You can also write this using the `year` function (which I personally find easier to read):

```
  SELECT TOP 1 YEAR(TransactionDate), COUNT(PK) AS CountForYear
  FROM Orders o
  WHERE YEAR(TransactionDate) > 2002
  GROUP BY YEAR(TransactionDate) 
  ORDER BY COUNT(PK) DESC ;
```

Your original query had single quotes around `'2002'`.  This is unnecessary.  You should express numeric constants without single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.